# Trouble with adding pip's system environment variable

Tags: python, path, pip

I was able to install pip by using `distribute_setup.py` and `get-pip.py`. However, I had to add pip to path by adding *C:\Python27\Scripts*.

This worked for a little while but I had to do a system restore for other reasons and now when I type pip in the command prompt it returns: `'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command`.

I tried adding `C:\Python27\Scripts` to path again both to the user variable and system variable but to no avail. I also tried re-installing pip but it just said I had the latest version installed already. Pip can be imported without any error within python so I am at a loss here. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `easy_install`

`easy_install -U pip`

This will remove `pip`.

If you don't have `easy_install` ... installed, do that first.

After uninstalling `pip`, simply reinstall it using the `get-pip.py` file.